# how to console.log() duplicates inside arrays?

Tags: javascript

why does this for loop print `a` , `o` one time only, when `lst_` has two `a` and two `o` ?
how to fix , solve this to show all the items

if you use `console.log(x);` then you can see each one in the console, when this line is commented the console has only a,i,o each one a single time

```js
var lst_ = [ "a", "a", "i", "o", "o" ];
var x ; 
for (x =0;  x < lst_.length ; x++) { 
    console.log(lst_[x]);
//  console.log(x);

}
```

Comment: It seems fine here. Where have you met the problem?

Comment: It is fine here

Comment: This is a setting in your console window. It's called "group similar" and can be accessed in the top-right corner by clicking the cogwheel (assuming chrome)

Comment: because bot a and o repeating two times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the console closely. You'll see there is a number in a blob to the left of the message.

This means that there were that number of *identical, sequential* messages logged to the console.

They just aren't shown one-by-one to avoid flooding the console (which becomes an issue when, for instance, you have something being logged every second) and obscuring other messages.

[image: screenshot of console]

You can turn "group similar" off in the console settings.

[image: screenshot of console settings]

Answer (score 1):

If same values occurs again, the console will indicate it with a number as follows.
In your case the 'a' prints 2 times in sequence, so it shows 2 in right side.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the right of your console, you see a number. This number represents the times the same line would have been printed. If you would change the order of your array, e.g. like this: `[ "a", "i", "o", "a", "o" ]`, you should see every line